# Python - Defining variables with dictionaries

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, analysis

So I'm trying to store a couple of conditional dictionaries in a couple of variables.

```
to_dict = ['a', 'b', 'c']
vars = ['x', 'y', 'z']

for i, j in zip(enumerate(to_dict, start=1), enumerate(vars, start=1)):
    j[1]=dict(some_calculation of i[1])
```

The above says, 'tuple object doesn't support item assignment.'
Also tried turning the 'vars' to list, which says 'too many values to unpack.

The output I need when I print x, y or z is

```
{'key1': value1, 'key2': value2..}
```

Pretty sure there's a blunder and I apologize.

Comment: enumerate returns a tuple, it returns the a number (for the loop) and the variable. Your first i is probably something like (1, 'x') and j is (1, 'a'). Thereby you are trying to assign something to your variable, which is probably not what you intend to do. Please explain what you want and we can help you figure it out, but for now we can only point out the error in your code.

Comment: Please clarify this with some sample input data and show **exactly** what output you're hoping for

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to assign variables dynamically, this is an anti-pattern.

Use your dictionary:

```
out = {k: some_calculation(x) for k, x in zip(vars_, to_dict)}
```

Output (here leaving the values unchanged):

```
{'x': 'a', 'y': 'b', 'z': 'c'}
```

Then use `out['x']` to access the output of your function on `'x'`.

Side note, if you want to `enumerate` in a loop, just do it once:

```
for i, (v, x) in enumerate(zip(vars_, to_dict), start=1):
    print(i, v, x)
```

Output:

```
1 x a
2 y b
3 z c
```